# What will happen first: the rod's front end will hit the back wall of the cave or the left end of the rod will enter the cave?

Tags: special-relativity

A rod flies into a cave at the speed of 0,8c relative to the cave. In the reference frame of a stationary observer, the cave is 30 meters deep. According to the observer, who "sits" on the rod, the rod is 30 meters long.  Thus,  in the frame of the stationary observer, the rod will be 18 meters long and in the frame of the moving observer, the cave will have the depth of 18 meters (since the cave moves towards the rod at the speed 0,8c).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox

Comment: We have several question about the so-called "barn and ladder" paradox (of which this is a variant) on the site already. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/pole-and-barn-paradox And on the nail and hole (or rivet and bug variation) paradox as well: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/180998/hole-and-nail-paradox-in-special-relativity

Comment: Short answer though: The two events are separated by a _[spacelike interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_intervals)_. There can be no _causal relationship_ between spacelike-separated events, and the laws of physics do not require observers in different frames to agree upon which one happened first in that case.